# memoir class \part style

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, parts

I am preparing a book in memoir class. I use `\chapterstyle{madsen}`, which uses a sans serif font (I don't know which one). I also have parts and I would like to have the parts to be typeset in the madsen style as well (if I can get the font to be the same, I would be satisfied).

Second, if I can get the section titles to be in the same font, it would be great. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the definition of the `madsen` chapter style:

```
\makechapterstyle{madsen}{% requires graphicx package
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
    \normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
    \normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}%
      \resizebox{!}{4ex}{%
        \chapnamefont\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \chapnamefont \phantom{\printchaptername \chapternamenum%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}%
        \resizebox{!}{4ex}{%
          \chapnamefont\bfseries\sffamily 1}%
      }%
    }%
    \afterchapternum %
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{%
    \par\hspace{1.5cm}\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}}
```

The relevant parts are: `\normalfont\Large\scshape` for the font of the chapter name (i.e., the string "Chapter") and `\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily` for the chapter titles (the chapter numbers require other specifications that won't be used).

To obtain the same settings for part headings, you can redefine `\partnamefont`, `\partnumfont`, and `\parttitle` font to use similar settings; for section headings, you can use `\setsecheadstyle`. Here are the changes required:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\chapterstyle{madsen}

\renewcommand\partnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape}
\renewcommand\partnumfont{\normalfont\Large\scshape}
\renewcommand\parttitlefont{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}
\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks very much for your assistance.