# How can I make a memoir style like this thesis?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

This answer links a nice thesis: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263586/512

How can I make a memoir style like it?

I guess I might start with the madsen style, which is given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82917/512

Comment: I think you may also find this post useful http://www.latextemplates.com/template/tufte-style-book, in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chapter styles are described in the `memoir` manual.  Here's my attempt.

```
\makechapterstyle{neil}{% requires graphicx package
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{10pt}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{90}{120}\selectfont\bfseries\color{\colorchapnum}}%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\color{\colorchaptitle}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
  \vspace{\afterchapskip} {\textcolor{\colorchaptitle}{\hrule}} \vspace{\afterchapskip}}%

}
```

[image]